# Group array elements by more than 1 field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var array = [{id: 123, user: "tester", text: ["wow]},
             {id: 123, user: "random", text: ["nice", "cool"]},
             {id: 1245, user: "random", text: ["good"]},
             {id: 1245, user: "tester", text: ["neat"]},
             {id: 123, user: john", text: ["neat", "good", "bye"]},
             {id: 12456, user: "tester", text: ["Bye"]},
             {id: 1245, user: "random", text: ["wow"]},
             {id: 1245, user: "john", text: [{"wow", "nice"]}];
```

Let's say the main user is "tester" and everyone else is secondary. I want to know how many texts the main user has for each id and how many texts the other users has for the same id.

So, the array should return:

```
finalArray = [{id: 123, tester: 1, random: 2, john: 3},
              {id: 1245, tester: 1, random: 1, john: 2},
              {id: 12456, tester: 1}]
```

Comment: okay. were is your code?

Comment: have a go using lodash
https://lodash.com/docs this will probably be your best options.

of you run into problems and need help have a search.
If you cant find the answer create a new post.

SO isnt a free developer service for someone to write your code for you

Comment: Show us what you've tried. These arrays aren't even valid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  -> https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Lu1da4a4/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for the objects with the same `id` and assign the length of the `text` array to the a property with the user's name.

This solution features a closure over the hash table and uses [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for getting a new array with the grouped result.

```js
var array = [{ id: 123, user: "tester", text: ["wow"] }, { id: 123, user: "random", text: ["nice", "cool"] }, { id: 1245, user: "random", text: ["good"] }, { id: 1245, user: "tester", text: ["neat"] }, { id: 123, user: "john", text: ["neat", "good", "bye"] }, { id: 12456, user: "tester", text: ["Bye"] }, { id: 1245, user: "random", text: ["wow"] }, { id: 1245, user: "john", text: ["wow", "nice"] }],
    result = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.id]) {
                hash[a.id] = { id: a.id };
                r.push(hash[a.id]);
            }
            hash[a.id][a.user] = a.text.length;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to the problem you have specified:

```
var res = [];
var obj = {};
for(var i in array) {
    if(array[i].user == 'tester') {
        if(obj[array[i].id])
            obj[array[i].id].tester++;
        else 
            obj[array[i].id] = {tester: 1};
    } 
}              
for(var i in array) {
    if(obj[array[i].id] && obj[array[i].user] != 'tester') {
        if(obj[array[i].id][array[i].user])
            obj[array[i].id][array[i].user]++;
        else
            obj[array[i].id][array[i].user] = 1;
    }
}
for(var i in obj) {
   var temp = obj[i];
   temp.id = i;
   res.push(temp);
}
console.log(res);   //output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use latest es6 features map/findIndex and achieve this

Check the following snippet

```js
var arr1 = [{
    id: 123,
    user: "tester",
    text: ["wow"]
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    user: "random",
    text: ["nice", "cool"]
  },
  {
    id: 1245,
    user: "random",
    text: ["good"]
  },
  {
    id: 1245,
    user: "tester",
    text: ["neat"]
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    user: "john",
    text: ["neat", "good", "bye"]
  },
  {
    id: 12456,
    user: "tester",
    text: ["Bye"]
  },
  {
    id: 1245,
    user: "random",
    text: ["wow"]
  },
  {
    id: 1245,
    user: "john",
    text: ["wow", "nice"]
  }
];
let finalResult = [];
arr1.map((item) => {

  const resIdx = findFinal(item.id);
  if (resIdx === -1) {
    const obj = {
      id: `${item.id}`
    }
    const userName = item.user
    obj[userName] = 1;
    finalResult.push(obj)
  } else {
    const resObj = finalResult[resIdx]
    const userName = item.user
    if (resObj.hasOwnProperty(userName)) {
      resObj[userName] += 1;
    } else {
      resObj[userName] = 1;
    }
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult))

function findFinal(id) {
  return finalResult.findIndex((res) => res.id === id.toString());
}
```